Ex-Vietnam soldiers heist film 1976-1984; main characters are white men disguised as Afro Americans
Would appreciate any help in finding an Ex-Vietnam soldiers heist film, possibly B movie. It was an English speaking film set in America. One character speaks using a voice box and he has a scar on his face. The main characters are white men disguised as Afro Americans. Likely era: 1976-1984, might be earlier or a bit later.
There are flashbacks within the film to the robber's former life as a soldier in hospital. This film was on Betamax video in London in 1984. The man with the voice box had one arm and the twist at the end was that the white colonel was a black man who carried out the mission for the dead white colonel. Many Thanks! Vinnie

You're looking for Zebra Force (AKA Code Name: Zebra) from 1976.

The film opens with a raid on an illegal casino performed by a group of blacks with automatic weapons. The audience discovers the perpetrators are white disguised as blacks. The story moves to a Vietnam War flashbacks with a patrol being ambushed by the Vietcong, and the resulting firefight. The leader of the vigilante veterans is a man known simply as the Lieutenant who was their platoon leader and disfigured in the action. Recuperating in a hospital he regroups the survivors for a series of escalating raids to not only to enrich themselves, but to wipe out organised criminal gangs involved in illegal gambling and narcotics distribution.

The leader's face is scarred, he has one arm and uses a voice box. It's revealed in the end that it was a disguise and he's really a black man who switched identities with a white friend in the hospital. Followed by a sequel who was confusingly also called Code Name: Zebra in 1987. Here's the trailer:




Hi Walt, I seen this fim when I was young and could not remember the name.  I've been trying to find the name for about 2 months until a friend told me about stack exchange. Thank you so much.
